# Django settings, module specific settings

Tags: python, django

We have this model on Django app

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    # A constant 
    MY_CONSTANT = 'this is a constant'

    field1 = models.Charfield()
    field2 = models.Charfield()

    def some_method(self):
        if field1 == MY_CONSTANT:
            do_some_stuff()
```

So my question is should I put MY_CONSTANT inside model class or should I put it in django settings with MODULE (namespace) prefix:  `MYMODEL_MY_CONSTANT = 'this is a constant'`

The scenario is that constant may be used in another module. If put in Model, we can import model and use via MyModel.MY_CONSTANT. What is the best practices for this?

Answer (score 1):

Is it a configurable setting, or is it just a constant? If the latter, it should be defined on the model (as you have it above); if the former, put it in the settings config.